# Is it possible to get the timestamp of a SQL datetime column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server and I have a table with a `datetime` column.

When I run a query `SELECT END_DATE FROM CUSTOMER` I get `2007-12-03 10:15:30.000`

I would like to run a query that returns a unix timestamp like `1543357818` representing the date and time. Is this possible through SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `datediff()`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', END_DATE)
FROM CUSTOMER
```

Comment: `datediff` returns an integer. I need to return a long. Otherwise I'm seeing this error `The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large.`

Comment: hmm... `DATEDIFF_BIG` seems to work. There's no better way to do this I assume

Comment: hmm.. there's another thing. This assumes the date in the column is already UTC time. But the column values I have are set for my local time zone

Comment: @RonApple1996 . . . You can use `datediff()` but signed integers will work until at least the 2030s.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, convert to float and do a subtract, then convert to seconds. Obviously you can change some of this to constants, but this illustrates what I'm doing:

```
select floor((convert(float,getdate())-convert(float,convert(datetime,'1970-01-01')))*24*60*60)
```